# on('click') not working?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a button that will hide a div that it is contained in.  The contents of this div (including the button) will most likely be destroyed and recreated several times while the page is being viewed, so I've been advised to use "event delegation" to target the button, as having a function actually called at the button itself fails after it's been destroyed and recreated.

The syntax it was suggested I use is as follows:

```
$('#container').on('click', '#button', function() {
  $('#div').fadeOut();
});
```

This isn't working, for some reason.  I've created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QgGsP/), wherein it isn't working either.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

EDIT: Okay, apparently I'm dumb and wasn't using jsfiddle right.  Once I configured it to use jQuery, it works fine, but this method isn't working in my actual code.

HTML:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" id="slideshow">
  <div class="cycle-overlay custom" id="info">
    <img src="close_pane.png" class="fadein close_pane button">
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#slideshow').on('click', '.close_button', function() {
  $('#info').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

This looks functionally the same to me, but isn't working.  Any idea why?

Comment: set the framework on the Left hand side to jQuery instead of MooTools and it should work.. Working fiddle here  http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/QgGsP/1/

Comment: totally works if you use jQuery instead of Mootools

Comment: You didn't select jquery to load in your jsfiddle - I've updated it: http://jsfiddle.net/QgGsP/3/

Comment: I'm not sure this is a valid question, then, if it's just a missing setting in jsFiddle.  That, or it should be tagged as 'jsFiddle'.  If you're still having problems in your real code, you should provide some additional context.

Comment: @Sushanth-- you should add your comment as an answer as you seem to have been the first person to respond to the (current) solution.

Comment: Ah, hm.  Well then that's not the issue I'm having, as it isn't working in my code.  I'll update my question with my code.

Comment: @DavidHoerster ..Thanks for that .. I think it makes more sense to add it as a comment as its a trivial issue.. ;)

Comment: @NaOH . Let me take a wild guess.. Maybe you seem to destroy the #container as well .. Delegate it to a higher parent and then try again.. $('body').on('click', '#button', function() {

Comment: That seems like it might be a good idea, but it doesn't work even if nothing's been destroyed yet (no slides have been cycled, in my particular case).

Comment: @NaOH .. Looks like you don't have this class anywhere in your HTML '.close_button'   .. That looks like '.close_pane'   to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you do not have the element with class `.close_pane` in your `HTML`

```
$('#slideshow').on('click', '.close_button',
```

supposed to be

```
$('#slideshow').on('click', '.close_pane',
```

Comment: *puts head in hands*  Apparently I'm very tired.  Thank you.

Comment: @NaOH .. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 3):

It is all good: http://jsfiddle.net/pulkitm/QgGsP/4/

You just missed choosing the jquery framework on the left panel!

The code just works fine:

```
$(function() {
    $('#outer').on('click', '#close', function() {
        $('#inner').fadeOut();
    });
});​
```